# Programmatically generate dashboard reports in Superset

Tags: dashboard, apache-superset, amazon-quicksight

I have a client who's currently looking for a dashboarding solution where they want the users of their platforms to be able to programmatically generate a report from a dashboard with a button click. The dashboard will need to be embedded into a 3rd party application. Is there any way to do with with Superset? I didn't see any exposed [APIs](https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/) that allow this functionality. I know AWS QuickSight has this capability but it's somewhat too expensive for my client's use case.

Thanks in advance!